# Clicking every button that contains a specific class name with ChromeDriver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver and I would like it to click every button on the page that contains a specific class name.

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);

driver.Url = "https://www.some-url.com";
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2);
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("some-class-name")).Click();
```

However that only clicks on one button. How could I achieve this to click every button found on the web-page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `FindElements` instead of `FindElement`

```cs
IList<IWebElement> list= driver.FindELements(By.ClassName("some-class-name");
foreach (IWebElement element in list)
{
    element.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<WebElement> elementName = driver.findElementsBy.ClassName("some-class-name"));
```

This will return a list of `WebElements` which you can iterate over in a foreach statement, performing `.click()` on each.